# How to Pass a Character Array to a Function Expecting a void* Pointer?

Tags: c, termios, unistd.h

I'm using the termios.h and unistd.h library to read from a serial port via the [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) function

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

The following code works just fine calling the read function:

```
char read_buf [256];

int n = read(serial_port, &read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
```

Now I'm trying to create a function (readSerial) that calls read() and passes it a pointer to read().  I hardcoded "256" for troubleshooting purposes.

```
void readSerial(char* msg) {
    int num_bytes;

    num_bytes = read(serial_port, &msg, 256);
}

void main(void) {

char serial_rmsg[256] = {0};

readSerial(serial_rmsg);
printf(serial_rmsg , "%s");
}
```

I can't figure out to how pass a character array into readSerial such that the `void *buf` argument of read(2) will accept it.

I tried the above code and read() won't write characters to the address I've provided at &msg.

Comment: because you need to use a double pointer

Comment: Where is serial_port declared? Is it a global variable?

Comment: An array will decay to a pointer in function parameters, and there's an implicit conversion to and from a `void *`. `&read_buf` is not a `char *`, it is a pointer to an array[256] of `char`. Does the compiler not warn about that?

Comment: Is this the same code? Double check the call to `printf()`. And what is `serial_port`?

Comment: Just in case you're still having trouble, when you pass `&msg` to `read`, it is pointing to the _pointer_ variable and _not_ what that variable points to. Change to: `num_bytes = read(serial_port, msg, 256);` Even for the code that _was_ working, leave off the `&` (it's harmless there, but not idiomatic. You _could_ do: `&msg[0]`). The `&` is _not_ harmless inside the `readSerial` function.

Comment: is this a serial port or just the name? An actual serial port isn't quite so easy.

Comment: Discarding/ignoring the return code from the **read()** syscall is usually bad practice (especially for a serial terminal), and instead of a predictable & robust program, can produce erratic and/or non-portable code.

Comment: You've reversed the arguments to `printf()`.

Comment: This problem here is a nice illustration why ancient crap API functions like `read` are dangerous and needed to be replaced with something better designed like 30 years ago... Void pointers are increasingly irrelevant with all the new type-generic featues of C since C11 and C23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You originally passed a pointer to an array. But it's equally valid to pass a pointer to an array's element. These both point to the same place. They have different types, but it doesn't matter since we're (implicitly) casting the pointer to a `void *`.

And it's why you could have used the following initially:

```c
char read_buf[256];

int n = read( serial_port, &( read_buf[0] ), sizeof( read_buf ) );
```

An array used as a pointer degenerates into a pointer to its first element, so that can also be written as follows:

```c
char read_buf[256];

int n = read( serial_port, read_buf, sizeof( read_buf ) );
```

And that's exactly what you are doing when you call `readSerial`.

```c
readSerial( serial_rmsg, sizeof( serial_rmsg ) )
```

is short for

```c
readSerial( &( serial_rmsg[0] ), sizeof( serial_rmsg ) )
```

In other words, you're already passing a pointer. And so your function should simply look like this:

```c
void readSerial( char* msg, size_t n ) {
   ...
   num_bytes = read( serial_port, msg, n );
   ...
}
```